# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 in sharepoint server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are facing an error as mentioned in the title. What are the possible causes for this error? Site was working perfectly before this.

Comment: As you find easily on google if you search the error code: your database is probably full (disk space, or soft-limit if you use sql express)

Comment: @RobertLindgren my content db size is currently 2.6 GB, and my hard drive over which SQL is installed has more than 76GB free space. But still I am getting this error while creating items in document library programmatically. Any suggestion?